# Hadoop / Hive upgrade performance

Tags: hadoop, hive, upgrade

We are testing Hive and Hadoop for digging in our data and I installed a while back Hadoop 1.2.1 and Hive 0.11 (was the stable version)

Test server is 4 cores and 16GB of ram.

Now I wanted to know if switching to Hive 0.12 and Hadoop 2.2 is worth the trouble of upgrading the server in terms of performance on queries?

A query looks like this:

```
SELECT i, day(time), count(distint value), count(*) from table lateral view explode(column) tab AS i group by i, day(time);
```

So a bit of everything in my query is used but I couldn't find decent info on performance gain when upgrading.

Any insight on this matter would be nice :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query doesn't contain "where" predicate, you cannot enjoy Predicate Pushdown to storage layer introduced in 0.12, even if you data is in ORC format.

Thus, although among 0.12 improvements are faster plan generation and optimization to COUNT, the educated guess, I believe, should be that the performance improvement will not be dramatic.

Comment: This was an 'test' query to perform a benchmark :) More queries will be tested in the future so I guess an upgrade is due :)

Answer (score 0):

For that sort of query the only benefit you could expect in upgrading to Hive 12 would be if you had a large number of partitions. Apache JIRA HIVE-4051 has more info if you're interested.